# PHP - MySQL statement always set value to 1 when UPDATE SET

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, wamp, lamp

```
foreach ($_POST as $nazwa_checkboxa=>$id) {
    $s = "SELECT uprawnienie FROM user WHERE Id_user=".$id;
    $helpdesk = 0;

    if ($s == 0) {
        $helpdesk = 1;
    }

    $z = "UPDATE user SET uprawnienie = ".$helpdesk." WHERE Id_user=".$id;
    $wynik = $polaczenie->query($z);
    $zmienione++;
}
```

Column `uprawnienie` return `0 = normal` user and `1 = administrator`
The update always set value to 1 and I can change user to administrator (0 to 1) but it doesnąt work 1 to 0

Comment: Putting `$_POST` data directly into your query is a [psuper bad idea](http://bobby-tables.com/). Is this PDO? Using prepared statements would help here in a huge way.

Comment: Ummm... you never execute the first query!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do it using one query, e.g.:

```
update user
set uprawnienie = (SELECT if(uprawnienie=1,0,1) FROM user WHERE Id_user = '<id>')
where Id_user = '<id>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't actually run the `query()` for `$s`.  Therefore, the `if ($s==0)` is not checking the query results, but rather whether `"SELECT..."==0`.  Per the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php), "Strings will most likely return 0" when cast to integers for such comparisons.